# How to upgrade pandas on google colab

Tags: python, pandas, pip, google-colaboratory

As I understand in Google Colab environment pandas is pre-installed. However the version it use it's not the recent one.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
>>0.22.0
```

When I want to install the latest version using

```
!pip install pandas==0.23.4
```

It is still use the 0.22.0 version instead of a new, even though the log message mentioned that 0.22.0 was successfully uninstalled.

How should I upgrade properly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to restart the kernel.

```
!pip install pandas==0.23.4
```

Restart Google Runtime In toolbar go to

> Runtime->Restart Runtime...

Then try

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the restart runtime as part of the script? [I need pandas>=1.2.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41150#issuecomment-1007659936) and I can upgrade it like this. But when I come back to the same script days after, pandas version has fallen back to 1.1.5 again (I would like the script to run without any user interaction)

Comment: Yes. u can kill the kernel using os module.

Answer (score 0):

This is the newest version:

```py
! pip install pandas==0.25
```