# Passing a function in pandas agg method of a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

This is in google colab

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['state1', 'state2', 'state1', 'state1', 'state2'], 
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                   'C': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})
print(df)

      A     B    C
0   state1  1   10
1   state2  2   11
2   state1  3   12
3   state1  4   13
4   state2  5   14
```

This is the DataFrame. If we use the built-in 'max' function with the `agg` function it is working fine.

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['C'].agg('max')

      A     C
0   state1  13
1   state2  14
```

But if we use a `lambda` function is raising an error

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['C'].agg(lambda x: x.max())

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Why is this raising a error? What is the difference between passing a lambda function and a built-in function in the `agg` method?

Even for me it is not working in jupyter notebook also
[image]

Comment: They both work for me on `1.1.0`

Comment: Both of them works for me on `0.25.1`

Comment: It works even on `0.25.1` do you mind to tell which version are you using?

Comment: Write an entire test program, run it on a fresh console, then post the program and the output here.

Comment: I am running this in google colab and it is not working here

Comment: Is there any way to correct this problem?

Comment: in google colab check your version of pandas.. Upgrade using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53085629/6361531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously when I run the question for the first time the pandas version was 1.0.5.

But after then i updated the version to 1.1.0 and ran the same thing and it works fine.

```
!pip install pandas==1.1.0
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['state1', 'state2', 'state1', 'state1', 'state2'], 
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                   'C': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})

print(df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['C'].agg(lambda x: x.max()))

       A     C
0   state1  13
1   state2  14
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False)[['C']].agg(lambda x: x.max())
```